# Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

After converting my project to swift 3, I get the following `Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet'` error on the first line within this block:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init (hex:String) {
        var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercased() // error appears on this line

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = (cString as NSString).substring(from: 1)
        }



        let rString = (cString as NSString).substring(to: 2)
        let gString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 2) as NSString).substring(to: 2)
        let bString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 4) as NSString).substring(to: 2)

        var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
        Scanner(string: rString).scanHexInt32(&r)
        Scanner(string: gString).scanHexInt32(&g)
        Scanner(string: bString).scanHexInt32(&b)


        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1))
    }
}
```

I'm guessing the error derives from a change in syntax with `'stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet'` .. what is the correction for this?

Comment: You should be asking yourself why you can't discover the answer on your own.

Comment: Have you tried typing in `hex.trim` and seeing what the auto-complete finds for you? Or looking at the ["Apply API Guidelines to the Standard Library"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md) evolution proposal?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The new syntax is like this:

```
var cString = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
```

As a suggestion, you don't need to specify that `cString` is a String, as this is assumed with the value you are assigning to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this as well.

```
let trimmedString = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Swift 3 documentation; the new Swift 3 API is:

```
func trimmingCharacters(in set: CharacterSet) -> String
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1643030-trimmingcharacters

Answer (score 0):

And for an Int and Float how can I code it ?

```
    private var currentTotal_passengers: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        currentTotal_passengers = currentTotal_passengers.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)